# How can I disable 'factory reset' function?

Tags: root-access, settings

This is **not** a duplicate as I'm **not** trying to protect it against being **stolen**. I'm trying to protect it from **tech illiterate** people that keep resetting it. I basically need to make it so that I can only reset it though the PC. I have root and everything and I thought I disabled anything dangerous to them.

If we don't get any good ideas, can I just set it up to some sane defaults and then just delete the Settings app? (Good thing "Recovery" is protected by a hardware key combination.)

Comment: When you say "protected by a hardware key combination", it sounds like the people who are resetting your phone don't have access to the physical buttons. Perhaps your situation is one where [tag:kiosk-mode] would be easier and more helpful.

Comment: They don't have access to the combination because they don't know it. It's not like they're actively trying to find ways to mess up the device. I just need to do the equivalent of baby proofing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can disable Settings if you have root.  From a root shell or terminal:

```
pm disable com.android.settings
```

Run it again, changing `disable` to `enable`, when you want to use it later.